# how to give dhtmlx tabcontent variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX tabbar, I want to give the width of tabbar in the "%".I have a splitter,when ever I changed the position of the splitter,the tab content area position has to vary.

```
 <div id="rightTab"></div>
       var tabbar = new dhtmlXTabBar("rightTab", "right");
       tabbar.addTab("a1", "<span>Details</span>", "80px");
       tabbar.setContentHref("a1", "../../Home/Index/");
```

I have this tabbar inside my splitter.I gave height and width in (%),but it is not varying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change size of your div id "rightTab" - tabbar will resize with its parent container.